# Unable to run Scrapy: "ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3Download Handler':"

Tags: python, scrapy, importerror

I was going through the Scrapy tutorial but was unable to get past the first run. I've installed everything I could as 64 bit.

There are a few guides on installing Scrapy but I feel like I've done everything in them.

Any ideas to what my problem could be?

Thanks so much!

> 2013-08-23 21:53:28-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.18.0 started (bot:
>   tutorial)
>
> 2013-08-23 21:53:28-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available:
>   ssl, http11, django
>
> 2013-08-23 21:53:28-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings:
>   {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES':
>   ['tutorial.spiders'],  'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
>
> 2013-08-23 21:53:28-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats,
>   TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "G:\Program Files\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>
> File "G:\Program Files\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 168, in
>   
>       execute()
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 143, in
>   execute
>       _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 88, in
>   _run_print_help
>       func(*a, **kw)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in
>   _run_command
>       cmd.run(args, opts)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 46,
>   in run
>       spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\command.py", line 34, in
>   crawler
>       self._crawler.configure()
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 44, in
>   configure
>       self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self, self._spider_closed)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 62, in
>   **init**
>       self.downloader = Downloader(crawler)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader__init__.py",
>   line 73, in **init**
>       self.handlers = DownloadHandlers(crawler)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers__init__.py",
>   line 18, in **init**
>       cls = load_object(clspath)
>
> File "G:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 40, in
>   load_object
>       raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)
>
> ImportError: Error loading object
>   'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3DownloadHandler': DLL load
>   failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: "*I've installed everything I could as 64 bit.*": so some stuff is still 32-bit? You can't mix and match architectures.

Comment: Oops. I didn't realize there was a 64 bit version of pyOpenSLL [here](http://www.egenix.com/cryptodownload/?file=egenix-pyopenssl-0.13.0_1.0.0g_1.win-amd64-py2.7.msi)